# How do I refactor this Swagger API Spec

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have a few endpoints where I have some standard error responses like `404`, `401`, `403` and `default`. I want to refactor these responses to a Swagger definition but I am not able to achieve this. I tried a few tricks but it always resulted in parsing errors. Here is the yaml I have.

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: My API
  description: My API description
  version: 0.0.1
host: api.example.com
schemes:
  - https
basePath: /
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /users:
    get:
      operationId: getUsers
      summary: Get users
      description: Get all users
      tags:
        - Users
      responses:
        '200':
          description: An array of users
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/User'
        '401':
          description: Authentication required
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
        '402':
          description: Payment required
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
        '403':
          description: Unauthorized access
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
        '404':
          description: Not found
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
        default:
          description: Unexpected error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
  /games:
    get:
      operationId: getGames
      summary: Get games
      description: Get all games
      tags:
        - Games
      responses:
        '200':
          description: An array of games
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/Game'
        '401':
          description: Authentication required
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
        '402':
          description: Payment required
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
        '403':
          description: Unauthorized access
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
        '404':
          description: Not found
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
        default:
          description: Unexpected error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
definitions:
  User:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        description: Unique id of user
      name:
        type: string
        description: Name of user
  Game:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        description: Unique id of game
      name:
        type: string
        description: Name of game
  Error:
    type: object
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
        description: HTTP status code
      message:
        type: string
        description: Message describing error
```

Observe the repeating responses in `/users` and `/games`. How do I refactor and move them to `definitions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shared `responses` object to define the responses. Then refer them in the individual operations. From the [spec](http://swagger.io/specification/#responsesDefinitionsObject) about shared responses object:

> An object to hold responses to be reused across operations. Response
>   definitions can be referenced to the ones defined here.

While this would be a valid spec, Swagger-UI won't be able to parse from the shared responses except `default` response. Here is the [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/606) related to this.

Comment: That doesn't actually solve the issue effectively. I was looking for something where I can define an object say `ApiErrors` with properties like `401`, `402` etc and inherit that object under `responses` to a particular request.

Comment: afaik, that's not possible with current spec.

Comment: yeah, looks like that's the case. Accepting answer as the best case scenario as of now.